# In the movie retribution, why is the criminal mastermind the victim at the same time

Tags: plot-explanation

There is a movie released this year called **Retribution**. The plot involves the CEO of a certain company being blackmailed by some unknown psycho who plants a bomb underneath the seats of the car. If anyone tries to get off their seats then the bomb explodes. When the movie ends  everyone can see that it's the character **Anders** that was blackmailing them. This contradicts the scene where **Matt** is asked to kill **Anders**, the  voice of Anders and the unknown assailant are registered one after the other in this scene where the unknown assailant speaks from a phone and Anders speaks from the car consequently. Did the direction of this movie make an error?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.